# References for minimal norm of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, optimization, linear-transformations

In a few questions for upper bounds of the norm of solutions to some bilinear systems, we are often interested in the problem of the "minimal norm of a linear map":
$$
g(A) = \inf_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|,
$$
for some norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Is there a name for such a quantity, and are there references for it? Since the problem is nonconvex (and does not appear to have a natural relaxation or rewriting to make it so), it seems to be very hard in practice to solve exactly for arbitrary norms (but it is possible I may be wrong).

There do appear to be some easy cases. For example, when the norm is the usual Euclidean norm (*e.g.,* $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x^Tx}$), the solution is clearly the smallest singular value of $A$, but other norms do not really seem to appear in many places (though, it's quite likely my Google-fu is failing me!).

Additionally, there is some interest in somewhat-tight lower bounds for these quantities, which would be very useful.

Comment: This is the [induced/operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) of the linear map $A$.  It can be solved by convex optimization since the problem $\inf_{\|x\| \leq 1}\|Ax\|$ is equivalent.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm afraid it's not: note the $\inf$ vs. the $\sup$. In particular, what you've written $\inf_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Ax\|$ always has a value of 0 for any $A$ and norm $\|\cdot\|$. Otherwise the problem would be quite simple :)

Comment: Of course, that was very silly of me.

Comment: Also, if you have a specific norm that you're interested in, there might be a nice closed form for the infinimum.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick for square matrices. If $A$ fails to be invertible, then of course the infimum is zero. In the case that $A$ is invertible, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\inf_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| &= \inf_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = 
\inf_{y\neq 0}\frac{\|A(A^{-1}y)\|}{\|A^{-1}y\|} 
\\ & = \inf_{y \neq 0}\frac{\|y\|}{\|A^{-1}y\|} = \inf_{\|y\| = 1}\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}y\|}  = 
\left[\sup_{\|y\| = 1} \|A^{-1}y\|\right]^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$
A lower bound in the case that $A$ is rectangular.  If $A$ fails to have full column rank, then the infimum must be zero.  If $A$ does have full column rank, let $B$ be such that $BA = I$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\inf_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| &= \inf_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = 
\inf_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|(Ax)\|}{\|B(Ax)\|} 
\\ & \geq 
\inf_{y\neq 0}\frac{\|y\|}{\|By\|}  = \inf_{\|y\| = 1}\frac{1}{\|By\|}  = 
\left[\sup_{\|y\| = 1} \|By\|\right]^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hey, thanks! We've derived a similar result, which is (as you've shown) tight in the case of invertible $A$, while the second case is not as clear for some computations in general cases. In this latter case, it is not fully clear to me how to compute this value exactly (though this bound appears to be somewhat tight in many practical cases), but I would be interested to know if anyone has looked at this latter problem, more generally :)

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris I wasn't able to find anything but maybe there's a terms used that I don't know about.  Anyway, are you interested in a particular kind of norm?  It might be possible to derive a discription of the infimum for the particular case (as with singular values in the $2$-norm case)

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris if you normalize $A$ so that $\|A\| = 1$, this is equivalent to computing the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of your matrix relative to the norm; that might get you some leads. This also seems like a good question to post to math overflow.